# How to get code from another schema of another environment

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to get plsql code from another environment like productions without any synonym or privilage using sql developer tool.

I think its like hacking or any trick to get using sql developer tool.

Comment: You can't see the source code of things you don't have the privileges to see. SQL Developer doesn't give you any additional privileges or magic access. If you are allowed then it will be visible in `all_source`. Otherwise, if you have a legitimate reason to need the source code then ask the owner of the other environment to supply it.

Comment: there should be a source code repo OUTSIDE the database as well, maybe you can ask where the code is controlled, maybe in a git repo? but otherwise, you must have the privs to access the code/objects/data that does not belong to you